# Data size limit. Error: Received message larger than max

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I am running a node script which connects to the business network and adds assets to the network. 
 I get the below error.

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Received message larger than max (5153800 vs. 4194304)

    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/sneha/node-app-v1/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:916:34)
    at <anonymous>
```

I followed this solved issue: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3301
and changed remote.js file in respective node modules  [ composer-playground,composer-client,composer-admin,composer-common etc.. ]

Even after the changes, I can't add the asset through the node script. It throws the same error.

If I add the asset through composer playground it successfully adds the asset but then I can't access the network [ in composer playground ] it throws this error

```
Error: No connection found with ID 2db7d182-8856-44d5-a9d8-5f7178726423
```

How can I solve both errors?
 
How can I set the limit to infinite?

I am using:

 Node version: v8.9.4
Composer version: v0.16.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change grpc message limits requires you to create/update your connection profile. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile
for information about connection profiles.
A no connection profile with id found usually implies you have restarted playground, but not restarted your interaction with playground. Would suggest closing the playground tab and creating new tab to use playground in.